# Do ALL browsers ignore a space at the start of a line of text?

Tags: html, cross-browser

I have two words on a line, with a `<br>` between them. The `<br>` has `display:none`

```
<h1>First<br> Second</h1>
```

At smaller breakpoints the `<br>` has `dispay:block` and the second word goes on to a second line. Thankfully all the browsers I can test ignore the white space before the second word. I don't want the second line to start with a white space.

Is this true of all browsers?

For some very boring reasons the `<br>` has to come before the white space, not after it.

Comment: Yes they do - I think it's so that coding indents are ignored otherwise you'd have random spaces everywhere - if you want a space before your text, use a non-breaking space: `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I think I've worked out what the CSS specs are saying. Here is the relevant bit:

If a space (U+0020) at the beginning of a line has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line', it is removed.

So yes a white space at the beginning of a line will be ignored

Comment: Correct, and browsers handle this fine. The same ought to apply to spaces at the end of lines too, but in practice if you test some edge cases, browsers do some weird stuff.